# Integral with HeavisideTheta takes too long to evaluate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier, persisting through 13.2 or later**

---

I tried to compute $$\int_{-1}^1 d x_1 \int_{-1}^1 d x_2 \int_{-1}^1 d y_1 \int_{-1}^1 d y_2 \theta(x_1 x_2 + y_1 y_2)\,$$ where $\theta$ is Heaviside's step function, by using

```
Integrate[HeavisideTheta[x1 x2+y1 y2],{x1,-1,1},{x2,-1,1},{y1,-1,1},{y2,-1,1}]
```

but it took forever to evaluate.  I didn't have the patience to wait until the end.  However,

```
Integrate[Boole[x1 x2+y1 y2 >= 0],{x1,-1,1},{x2,-1,1},{y1,-1,1},{y2,-1,1}]
```

was very quick.  Can anybody explain this strange behavior?

Comment: What about the case when `x1 x2 + y1 y2` is zero?  Perhaps you want `UnitStep`?

Comment: You might want to try UnitStep.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it's an integral so that shouldn't matter, and that's the whole point of it not evaluating at 0 I think, right?

Comment: @texasAUtiger, did you get better results with `UnitStep`? I got bored of waiting in both cases. But I have to admit I got bored quite fast

Comment: This is not a problem with multiple integration: even `Integrate[HeavisideTheta[x1 x2 + y1 y2], {x1, -1, 1}]` will take extremely long (if it finishes at all). For another clue, giving this one about 10 seconds shows that *MMA* creates an impossible integrand (for it) after the first integration, suggesting the complications it's running into: `Integrate[
 HeavisideTheta[x1 x2 + y1 y2], {x1, -1, 0}, {x2, -1, 0}, {y1, -1, 0}, {y2, 0, 1}]` (notice the limits of integration). Using `UnitStep` helps, but is extremely slow compared to `Boole` (which is used exclusively on `Integrate`'s help page).

Comment: @whuber Maybe because `HeavisideTheta` is a distribution not a function causes the symbolic integration slowdown. MMA is trying to do this properly. Just guessing...

Comment: It should be added to the valuable comment by @Kuba, that  `Boole[x1 x2+y1 y2 >= 0]` is a usual function, whereas `HeavisideTheta[x1 x2 + y1 y2]` is a distribution. BTW, [the Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) says nothing about definite integrals of distributions.

Comment: The output in 13.3.1 on Windows 10 is "Integrate::idiv: Integral of ((x1 x2+y1) (<<1>>))/y1+<<12>>+<<4>> does not converge on {-1,1}".

Answer (score 2):

As outlined in one of the comments, I think Mathematica is running into boundary value problems with the HeavisideTheta. More specifically, that Heaviside remains unevaluated at 0 itself, but you can integrate a function against the Heaviside in an arbitrarily small, open region including zero. If you fix this

```
Timing[
x = 1 + $MachineEpsilon;
Integrate[HeavisideTheta[x1 x2 + y1 y2], {x1, -x, x}, {x2, -x, x}, {y1, -x, x}, {y2, -x, x}]]
```

the integral computes

```
Out[7]= {13.1659, 8.}
```

You figured out that using Boole is faster and the better choice. So I guess the answer to your question is: issues with HeavisideTheta[0] remaining unevaluated.

Comment: I really don't understand why Mathematica has decided to keep HeavisideTheta[0] as unevaluated. Lots of problems for users would be avoided.

Comment: In  13.3.1 on Windows 10 this results in "Integrate::idiv: Integral of ((x1 x2+y1) (<<1>>))/y1+<<12>>+<<4>> does not converge on {-1,1}.".