# Integration of UnitStep or HeavisideTheta

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

I am using Mathematica 9.

If I evaluate

```
Integrate[Piecewise[{{1 - r, r > 0 && r < R}}, 0], r]
```

then I get

```
Piecewise[{{r - r^2/2, r > 0 && r - R < 0}}, 0]
```

This is wrong, because for $r>R$ it should evaluate $R-\frac{R^2}{2}$ instead of $0$.
I get the correct result, if I plug in R manually.

Is this a Bug?

Here is some minimal test code to visualize the problem

```
t1[r_] = Integrate[Piecewise[{{1 - r, r > 0 && r < R}}, 0], r]
t2[r_] = Integrate[Piecewise[{{1 - r, r > 0 && r < 1}}, 0], r]
Plot[{t1[r] //. R -> 1}, {r, -0.5, 2}]
Plot[{t2[r] //. R -> 1}, {r, -0.5, 2}]
```

[image]

The plots and the function definitions are only to visualize the problem.

- This problem also appears in a similar way when integrating UnitBox[R
  r]
- When using HeavisideTheta[R-Abs[r]] it doesn't even evaluate
- When using UnitStep[1-Abs[r]] and UnitStep[R-Abs[r]] both will result in the "wrong" evaluation
- Trying to use t[x_]=Integrate[...,{r,0,x}] will only make it worse, as I have to abort the evaluation after a minute or more. (same with := instead of =)

I think this question is related
[Integral with HeavisideTheta takes too long to evaluate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14417/integral-with-heavisidetheta-takes-too-long-to-evaluate)

Comment: Do you agree with the result of `D[Piecewise[{{r - r^2/2, r > 0 && r - R < 0}}, 0], r]` ?

Comment: Yes, I see your point. Then I should change the question to:
Why is Integrate[Piecewise[{{1 - r, r > 0 && r < R}}, 0], {r,-0.1,x}] not evaluating.

Comment: the integral in your comment works if you do as the error msg says and add `Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]]`

Comment: I didn't get such a message, but that actually solves my problem, thanks.

Comment: @george2079 - you should have posted your comment as an answer.